# Almost empty .htaccess file causing 500 error response

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 500-error

I created a test directory called "rewrite" and put a `.htaccess` file inside with a rewrite rule.

When I go to that URL through my browser I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

So I thought it was my rewrite syntax and tried a few changes, same thing. Then I commented out everything with # on each line. Same thing.

Then I noticed that the directory doesn't show up in its parent directory (which has no index file).

So then I tried changing the filename to `.htaccess_bad`, and the directory shows up.

Then I changed it back to .htaccess and emptied the file, so it a blank file. The directory still shows up.

Finally I added a single # to the .htaccess file, and viola, the directory disappears again.

I though the issue might be that the parent directory has a .htaccess file with a [R] flag on its rewrite rule, but removing that didn't fix the issue.

Any help on what to try next or why this is happening?

---

#### Quick update:

Even having a line break is causing issues. (so it has to be truly empty it seems).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess your .htaccess file is in `DOS` format and it needs to be in `Unix` format.

Answer (score 3):

Do not save .htaccess in UTF-8 encoding  and convert it to a regular ansi. In my case server don't like this BOM thing at the very begining of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ is cool. Try this:

Edit --> EOL conversion --> Convert to UNIX format

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never had this issue before, but...

When I opened up Putty and edited the .htaccess file server-side, it worked.

That's one point off for Notepad++.